# what is the correct way to inherit class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a base class as follows:

```py
class BaseSqlClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def some_func(env, db):
        # do something
```

I have a child class which inherits from base class as follows:

```py
class SqlGenerator(BaseSqlClass):
    def __init__(self, env, db, table):
        super().__init__()
        self.env = env
        self.db = db
        self.table = table
```

When i instantiate the child class, I get the error `__init__()` missing positional arguments, `__init__()` is of base class?
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why does the base class call its own `__init__` _from its own `__init__`_? And why does the child call `__init`?

Comment: Why is `BaseSqlClass.__init__` calling itself? What is that intended to do, other than infinite recursion?

Comment: Note I don't get an error about missing positional arguments, I get an error about a missing _method_. Given a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted does not fit to the code you posted, so I'll go with the code. First, you should be getting an error `maximum recursion depth exceeded` for

```py
class BaseSqlClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def some_func(env, db):
        # do something
```

When you create a `BaseSqlClass` instance, the `__init__` method is called, from which you call that same method again, which calls itself again, and so on. If you don't want to do anything at instance creation time, just omit the `__init__` method:

```py
class BaseSqlClass:
    @staticmethod
    def some_func(env, db):
        # do something
```

Second issue is in the second code snippet - you are calling some `__init` method of the parent class - but that doesn't have such a method. I guess you meant `super().__init__()` instead of `super().__init()` ?